# Windows cmd.exe command line: create a filelist by a loop

Tags: cmd.exe

I have several `VOB`-files on a DVD. 
The command

```
(for %i in (D:\VIDEO_TS\*.VOB) do @echo file '%i') > filelist.txt
```

in the Windows cmd command line returns `filelist.txt` with 
`file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_0.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_2.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_3.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_4.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_02_1.VOB'`

inside. *These are exactly the `VOB`-files located in `D:\Video_TS`.*

**Question:** How do I have to change the command syntax if I only want the files highlighted here in the list, that is only those with the  endings `01_1, 01_2, 01_3, 01_4`?

That means that `filelist.txt` is only

`file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_2.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_3.VOB'
file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_4.VOB'`

at the end.

PS: I tried command from that link https://ss64.com/nt/for.html but I don't get the correct one. I'm not familiar with the cmd syntax.

Comment: What do you mean? `01_1` ... `01_4` are not extensions first of all. Secondly, what is your exact requirement? Anything that has format of  `01_1` at the end of non-extension part of file name, higher than `01_0` and smaller than `02_0`? And lastly, what did you try?

Comment: See €dit. ;) ......

Comment: You still did not clarify how your requirements are related to the files that happen to match your pattern. Based on the incomplete specification, the following command produces the expected output without checking any files: `(for /L %i in (1,1,4) do @echo file 'D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_%i.VOB') > filelist.txt`

Comment: I edited something else. Next I should probably explain why I want to do this. Actually, I'm just interested in how I can do that. But the above command works. Thanks.

Comment: My command does not check what files exist, it simply prints fixed names with numbers from 1 to 4. You did not specify what you want to get if the DVD has more or less `VTS_01_*.VOB` files, e.g. 1..3 only or 1..5. See the first comment.

Comment: Ok I understand.
You mean so only a list with certain text content is created.
Yes, I need exactly the files mentioned for further processing with ffmpeg.

Comment: ms-dos was retired 22 years ago.  I removed the tag.

Comment: @cis I think I understand your reuqirement now, although I'm still not 100% sure. Do you need this in batch or can it be PowerShell? If you need it in batch exactly, why? You are supposed to specifiy **exact** attempts at solving this, not just "I don't got correct one", BTW.